# proving specific language is a NP-Complete

Tags: np-complete

I got this question and I'd happy for help.

$Satn^7$ is a language that containes all the CNF formula (P) which fulfill the next rule: There is a least $n^7$ satisfactory assignments, when n is the number of the variable in P.

I need to prove that $Satn^7$ is NP-Complete.

I tried reduction from SAT, when I add variable for each clause. But my big problem is that n is not known during the reduction, and also the number of variable for adding is change, and I didn't succss to find a rule about this changes.

Thank you

Comment: What is "stationing"? Do you mean assignments?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, as you already said, is by adding "dummy" variables, but not into existing clauses but into a new one which can always be satisfied (something like $(y\vee \neg y)$. Each new variable doubles the number of satisfying assignments, so it grows exponentially. Now, given that you add $k$ new variables, then the size of the output, $n$, is the size of P plus some linear function in $k$ and it **can** be computed by the machine performing the reduction.

Comment: Thank you, It helps me. But I still don't understand How I can to know the number of varuables in P? as I understood, You say that the reducntion's function will be calculate the number of new variables, and adding them to P. But is it polynomial algorithm? and also - where we take care of the fact that this is $n^7$? I need to add 7 caluses for one variable?

Comment: Go over P, bit by bit; each time you see a new variable, add it to a linked list; at the end sort the list and remove all duplicate values, and count its length. This is very obviously polynomial (and usually in such questions this implementation details are not needed)

Comment: As for $n^7$ - the only thing you need is to claim that there is a relatively small $k$ such that $2^k$ (number of satisfying assignments) is larger than $n^7$, n being the size of the new formula (hence linear in $k$). This happens for all $n^d$, for every constant $d$, since the exponential function grows much faster than polynomials.

Comment: @Gadi A: Thank you. I write the prove, but I have a difficult to prove the other side. If I have, for example CNF formula like this: $(x_1) and (not(x_1)) and (x_2) and (not(x_2))$, this is NOT satisfied, but in SATn^7 it will satisified.

Comment: Why is it satisfied in SATn^7? You still can't satisfy both the $x_1$ clause and the $\neg x_1$ clause.

Comment: @Gadi A: Thank you. and the last question (if you exhausted drom answer I will understand..). You said that "This happens for all nd, for every constant d, since the exponential function grows much faster than polynomials". But if I took a furmula with 2 variables, and one satisified assigment. When adding the "dummy variables", I got 9 satisfied assigments, when 9<2^7.
accutly, I prove that for any t variables in P, after adding the dummy variables, I will get 2^(t+1) satisfied assigments. I check it, and This claim (2_(t+1)>t^7)  is true just from n=36. What I missed?

Comment: I believe doing some reading about asymptotic growth analysis will be more helpful for you than I can; have you read CLR's book (Introduction to Algorithms)? Are you familiar with the big-oh notation? It seems to me you are missing some basic knowledge, without whom complexity theory is far more complicated than it should be.